# FFMPEG YouTube Settings

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, youtube

I successfully made it to work

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image file -i audio file -shortest -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 320k -profile:v high -level 4.0 -bf 2 -coder 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 10M -threads 4 -cpu-used 0 -r 30 -g 15 -movflags +faststart -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MYPRIVATEYTKEY
```

Now my question is: Does quality change if I don't add `-f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MYPRIVATEYTKEY` at the end?

Comment: We can't see where you are using `-f flv`... Adding `-f flv` doesn't affect the quality, because FLV is just the "container". I don't think you can choose other type of container for RTMP streaming.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific but i mean if i dont add -f flv will i lose quality or will it be the same. without -f flv? sorry im not very good explaining things

Comment: Does -f flv enhance quality or is it the same without -f flv?

Comment: i edited my question so you can see. The problem is that for some reason it does not accept -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MYPRIVATEYTKEY in ffmpeg so i deleted it and now im worried that is not the same without the -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/MYPRIVATEYTKEY

Comment: Without `-f flv`, there is an error `Unable to find a suitable output format...`. Adding `-f flv`  doesn't enhance the quality, and doesn't reduce the quality. FLV is just container/streaming protocol format. The codec, and the codec parameters affect the quality (for example: `-c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -g 15`).

Comment: Thank You so much.

Comment: The first part of this question doesn't appear to be relevant to the rest of the question. Explaining WHAT you got working to give appropriate context so that we know how that informs what you're doing in the rest of the question would make this a better question that is more helpful to others, which is the primary long-term goal of this site.